# Import methods/classes from another python file

Tags: python, add-on, import

I'm trying to use specific helper methods from another python file in my Blender addon. Although both my files "__init__.py" and "helpers.py" are located in the same directory, I keep getting a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'`.

```py
# __init__.py
import bpy
from helpers import my_register, my_unregister

def register():
    my_register()

def unregister():
    my_unregister()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I could work around this error by replacing `from helpers import ...` with `from . import helpers`, but then I'd have to use a prefix like `helpers.my_register()`. This gets especially ugly when using decorators:

```py
from bpy.app import handlers
from . import helpers

@helpers.eventhandler(handlers.frame_change_pre)
def on_frame_change_pre(dummy):
    ...

@helpers.eventhandler(handlers.frame_change_post)
def on_frame_change_post(dummy):
    ...
```

Is it possible to make `from {local file} import *` work in a Blender addon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `from . helpers import FOO` to import from a file at the same folder.